# how to fetch the url contents using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know the method in PHP (e.g. curl) to fetch the contents of a URL, but how can I fetch the contents of a URL using ajax?A clear way is not known. 
Below i have written a code but not able to see the contents from the url. How can i see the contents and can separte them into variable

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/100/",
    success: function(data) {
            $("body").append(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        },
   dataType: "jsonp"
});



</script>
```

This is my code. what should be added to this to see the contents of the url

Comment: If you are trying to fetch contents from different domain, then you can not do this using ajax due to Same-origin policy

Comment: If you are trying to fetch contents from different domain, then you can not do this using ajax due to same-origin policy

Comment: You can set `dataType: 'jsonp'` for getting data from other domains if you are using jquery ajax.

Comment: You can set dataType: 'jsonp' for getting the data from other domains if you are using jquery ajax.

Comment: I have added my code above but how can i see the contents obtained from url

Comment: Please help me somebody

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged jquery too, I assume you're open to use it. It has rather easy methods to get url contents.

If you want to update a container with the data obtained from request, you can use `$.get()` [(documentation)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Or, you can use `$.ajax()` [(documentation)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get contents and use in Javascript.